# disable button from two components in the same screen

Tags: angular

Im a beginner in angular.

I have a issue. I have 2 components and in both I call another component which contains a button that I use in both.
In some screen of the site the 2 appear together. My drawback is that I need to disable the 2 buttons regardless of which one is clicked. However, both buttons behave independently.
I have tried with the [disable] attribute, however only the button I click is affected.

the structure is like this:

component1   -    component2

```
  componentButton
```

but each button behaves independently

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to share that state between child components by using the parent component as a bridge:

#### Parent component

```html
<app-your-button [disabled]="buttonsDisabled" (click)="buttonAClicked()">
</app-your-button>

<app-your-button [disabled]="buttonsDisabled" (click)="buttonBClicked()">
</app-your-button>
```

```js
@Component({...})
export class Parent {
  
  buttonsDisabled = false

  buttonAClicked() {
     this.buttonsDisabled = true
  }
  buttonBClicked() {
     this.buttonsDisabled = true
  }
}
```

#### Button component

```html
<button [disabled]="disabled" (click)="click.emit()">
  Text
</button>
```

```js
@Component({...})
export class YourButton {
  @Input() disabled = false
  @Outpu() click = new EventEmitter<any>()

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, maybe I didn't understand myself very well.

I have 2 components, component A and component B in both I call component button like this
<app-place-order style="width: 100%;" ></app-place-order>

and the place order component looks like this
<button (click)="placeOrder()"
                    [disabled]="isDisable>Checkout <i </button>

Comment: from two components I call same child component but both buttons behave independently

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone who took the trouble to watch this incident.

What I basically did is the following.

I generated a service and in the service I established an onservable that finally in the child component I used and taking into account that it is an observable both buttons are disabled
I dont know if that is the better solution but it works in this case for me.